# Expresión regular, no consigo sacarla

Tags: mysql, regex

Buenas necesito sacar unos número de unas cadena de texto y no consigo sacar la expresión regular que necesito aquí el ejemplo.

```
Hola que tal #4702665

Bienvenido 45454545 tal #470815 BD. WA470815
```

Necesito que la expresión regular me haga lo siguiente me busque solo las XX esto es un ejemplo

XXXX XXX XXX X4702665

XXXXXXX XXXXXXX X X470815 XXXX XXXXXXX

Necesito que la expresión regular me busque todas las X. 
He estado cerca de conseguirlo pero siempre hay algo que me falta y no se que mas puede ser a ver si me puede ayudar alguien Gracias.

```
SELECT
Transaction.id,
Transaction.`comment`,
SUBSTRING(comment, '#([0-9]+)') AS user_id
FROM Transactio;
```

Solo puedo usar motor 5.7, por eso las expresiones del 8.0 no me sirven.

Comment: Sería necesario que pegaras el código que no te funciona o la sentencia sql en cuestión ;-)

Comment: No me quad muy claro que es lo que quires hacer. ¿Con "me busque todas las X" quieres convertir Hola que tal #4702665 en Hola que tal? o en #4702665?

Comment: quiero que la expresión regular me match las X por así decirlo. Un patrón que me busque todas esas X

Comment: Que tal compañero, aún no se entiende lo que necesitas, qué necesitas hacer con esas "X", quitarlas del string, contarlas, sobreponerlas a otro string? Si nos dices claramente, con gusto te podemos ayudar. Saludos cordiales

Comment: Lo que necesitas explicar es cual es el criterio para seleccionar o no seleccionar lo que querés extraer. Por ejemplo "quiero los números despues del # hasta el primer caracter no numérico o que sea final de linea"

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que obtengas todo el texto que no sea el número que aparece tras el `#`? Suponiendo que sólo hay un `#` por línea, la siguiente expresión regular te sacaría lo que buscas en dos grupos, uno para todo lo que aparece antes del `#` y otro para todo lo que aparece después (salvo el número): `(.*#)\d+(.*)`. Ejemplo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/sZwW24/1)

Comment: abulafia, si es exactamente eso lo que quiero pero no veo que me descarte el numero en el ejemplo que me has puesto falta algo mas?? o estoy poniendola mal. Gracias

Comment: @alfonsoPerez No es que descarte exactamente... es que la expresión tiene dos grupos de captura (los que van entre paréntesis), por tanto, tras el matching, en el primer grupo tienes parte de la respuesta y en el segundo grupo tienes la otra parte. Dependiendo del lenguaje que uses parar procesar la expresión regular, tendrás diferentes formas de acceder a esos grupos. Por ejemplo, si es una búsqueda con sustitución, en la parte de la sustitución en muchos lenguajes podrías poner `"\1\2"` y así se cambiaría el match completo por sólo los grupos, eliminando el número.

Comment: @abulafia y como podría aplicar ese método de substitución a una sql? por que lo desconozco totalmente.

Comment: Por favor, agrega en la pregunta la versión de mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es quedarte con todo lo que no sean números, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(comment, '\\d+', '')
```

Si además quisieras quitar la parrilla, utiliza:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(comment, '#?\\d+', '')
```

Para solo números que no formen parte de otra cadena:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(comment, '\\b\\d+\\b', '')
```

Igual que antes pero incluyendo la parrilla:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(comment, '(?:#|\\b)\\d+\\b', '')
```

**[Un ejemplo/Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/572Bya7rtZ3sKaPyJX4KtL/0)**

Comment: Me valdría si la DB la tuviera en 8.0 pero el problema es que la tengo en 5.7, no hay algo parecido para ese motor verdad no?.

Comment: No, si no voy mal creo que en mysql 5.7 para lo único que se pueden usar las expresiones regulares es para el filtrado en las condiciones del `where`. No podrías realizar la sustitución una vez recuperas el dato?

Comment: efectivamente ese es el problema que tengo en 5.7 solo puedo buscar la cadena con un patrón pero me devuelve 0 o 1, y necesito de devolución el dato, y eso si que no se tampoco como se haría. eso de la substitución que me comentas.

Comment: La idea sería recuperar el dato tal cual viene desde mysql, y luego con el lenguaje de programación que estés utilizando (qué utilizas?), encargarte de eliminar los números.